# Using audioqueue to stream audio. How to get the length of the audio file before playback ends?

Tags: iphone, streaming, audioqueueservices

Already finished implementing the player. I want to implement the progress bar. But I wonder if that's possible to do since we are streaming the music. Unless we are provided the length of the song before hand.

Please, I need your advice on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I found a way to do that and I succeeded. That you calculate the number of frames per packet of the song, and the average packet's size (in bytes). Use NSHTTPConnection to get the file size and use this formular:

**totalFrames = (fileSize * framesPerPacket / average packet size)**

when you have total frames, just divide it by the bitrate, then u get urself ***the total time!!***

Comment: This is slightly inaccurate because it doesn't account for space used up by metadata, file headers, etc.  The discrepancy should be small, but ideally there'd be a way of eliminating it entirely.  Unfortunately the API that should provide useful results (`AudioFileStreamGetProperty (stream, kAudioFileStreamProperty_AudioDataPacketCount, ...)`) never seems to actually provide a useful result, so unless there's another way I haven't found yet, this looks like the best option available.

Comment: Of course, there's always `kAudioFileStreamProperty_AudioDataByteCount`, which if it is present should be accurate...

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are given the size (or time length) of the audio file beforehand, there's no way you can set the range of your progress bar (you'll have no max).